# Js returns 0 instead on value

Tags: javascript

```js
function TipCalc(){
    var Amount = Number(document.getElementById("billamt").innerHTML);
    var TipPercent = Number(document.getElementById("tipper").innerHTML);
    var Answer = 0;
    alert(Amount,TipPercent);

    if (TipPercent > 0){
        Answer = Amount * TipPercent;
        document.getElementById("ac").innerHTML ="$ "+ Answer;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("ac").innerHTML = "Error!!";
    }
}
```

alert returns 0 instead of values
It's probably simple but i'm new to js

Comment: What value are you expecting alert() to return, and why?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: i was expecting the values enter into the html form

Comment: What's the HTML? If document.getElementById("billamt") refers to a text input then you probably need .value rather than .innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure on what it is you are trying to accomplish with the alert, is it for your reference on the code working or are you trying to calculate the values?

Either way I have modified your alert to show both values

```js
TipCalc()

function TipCalc(){
var Amount = Number(document.getElementById("billant").innerHTML);
var TipPercent = Number(document.getElementById("tipper").innerHTML);
var Answer = 0;
alert(`Amount:${Amount}, TipPercent: ${TipPercent}`);

if (TipPercent > 0){
    Answer = Amount * TipPercent;
    document.getElementById("ac").innerHTML ="$"+ Answer;
}
else{
    document.getElementById("ac").innerHTML = "Error!!";
}
}
function Number(elValue){
    return parseInt(elValue);
}
```

```html
<p id="billant">
42
</p>
<p id="tipper">
4
</p>
<div id="ac">

</div>
```